# How to sort files in a directory into different folders based on their diff result using Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, grouping, diff

I have a group of txt files with unique names in a directory, each has a unique name but and many of their contents are exactly the same. I need a good way to sort these txt files to separate folders such that all the files in each particular folders contain identical contents. The files needs a global diff to ensure the similarity.

for example, if 6 files have the following property (= means diff result are same)

```
a.txt = b.txt = c.txt
d.txt = e.txt != a.txt
f.txt != (a.txt nor d.txt)
```

Then, I need these files moved to directories like this:

```
/folder1/ contains (a.txt, b.txt, c.txt)
/folder2/ contains (d.txt, e.txt)
/folder3/ contains (only f.txt)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If they are truly byte-for-byte identical and that is the organizing criterion, just calculate a hash of every file (MD5, SHA1, whatever) and sort by hash value.  You don't even need perl, this could be easily done in bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't normally answer a question with no effort shown, but we tend to be a little more lenient with scripts than programs, and I was bored and wanted to refresh my awk skills a bit.

Here are two different ways using awk and Perl command-line scripts. These should be entered in one line.  Both were tested with a small set of files.

NOTE: These scripts DO NOT perform the actual operations. It is intended that you redirect the output into a file and then, after carefully verifying that it does what you want, execute that file as a script to perform the moves.

Perl:

```
for i in *.txt; do echo `sha1sum $i`; done | sort | perl -ne 
    'BEGIN {$a=1} 
     ($h,$f)=split; 
     if ($h ne $c) { $c=$h; $d="folder".$a++; print "mkdir $d\n"} 
     print "mv $f $d\n"'
```

Awk:

```
for i in *.txt; do echo `sha1sum $i`; done | sort | awk 
    'BEGIN {a=1} 
     $1!=c { c=$1; d="folder" a++; print "mkdir ",d} 
     {print "mv ",$2," ", d}'
```

They both use the same initial pipeline: run `sha1sum` on every file in the current directory, sort by hash value and then invoke either Perl or awk. 
You should run the pipeline by itself (omit the last `|` and the entire `awk` or `perl` command) to see what the raw output looks like.

The scripts look for a change in hash value and create a new folder each time it changes, then move the file and subsequent files with matching hashes to the new folder.

Given a set of 7 input files consisting of a single byte each:

```
Filename   Contents
--------   --------
a.txt      1
b.txt      2
c.txt      1
d.txt      1
e.txt      5
f.txt      1
g.txt      5
```

The raw pipeline output is:

```
$ for i in *.txt; do echo `sha1sum $i`; done | sort
5d9474c0309b7ca09a182d888f73b37a8fe1362c e.txt
5d9474c0309b7ca09a182d888f73b37a8fe1362c g.txt
7448d8798a4380162d4b56f9b452e2f6f9e24e7a b.txt
e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e a.txt
e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e c.txt
e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e d.txt
e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e f.txt
```

and the final output is

```
mkdir  folder1
mv  e.txt   folder1
mv  g.txt   folder1
mkdir  folder2
mv  b.txt   folder2
mkdir  folder3
mv  a.txt   folder3
mv  c.txt   folder3
mv  d.txt   folder3
mv  f.txt   folder3
```

BTW, this illustrates a rule you are wise to follow whenever writing scripts that do bulk operations.  Never have the script do the operation to begin with, have the script *write a script* that contains the bulk operations you want performed.  Upgrade to doing the actual operations only when you are *positive* it's been fully tested and debugged.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Garrison! I think the hash value would work in hash. I should have asked what would be good way to identify same files. It's my first time knowing comparing the hash value. Thank you again!